# Use CSS classes to style Kendo Editor template

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates, kendo-ui

I want to be able to add classes to HTML elements within a [Kendo](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/) template and then apply styling to them using CSS.

```
<style>
    .foo {
        color: red;
    }
</style>

<table class="table template">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th>C</th>
            <th>D</th>
            <th>E</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="foo">Foo</td>
            <td>Bar</td>
            <td>Baz</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<textarea id="myKendoEditor"></textarea>

<script>
let template = $(".template").get(0).outerHTML;
$("#myKendoEditor").data("kendoEditor").value(template);
</script>
```

This doesn't work, I guess because the markup within the template is not part of the DOM at the point where CSS get applied.

Is there any way to do this? The only success I've had is adding `style` attributes to the elements within the template but this is really nasty as I want to keep the style separate from the template.

Comment: You have to post the code whatever you had tried related your question so we can understand clearly why CSS properties are not working

Comment: Please add some code or provide us with a link to a working example. My guess would be that your CSS rules do not apply to your elements in the template.

Comment: It works [here](https://dojo.telerik.com/ArUgIwuz).